# Error using siunitx package: LaTeX error: "kernel/property-unknown"

Tags: errors, pdftex, siunitx

I have a problem with my TexLive installation. Whenever using the siunitx package on my machine, pdflatex aborts giving me the following error:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! LaTeX error: "kernel/property-unknown"
!
! The key property '.value_required:' is unknown.
!
! See the LaTeX3 documentation for further information.
!
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................
l.470 }
|'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
| This is a coding error.
|
| LaTeX has been asked to set the property '.value_required:' for key
| 'siunitx/detect-inline-family': this property is not defined.
|...............................................
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

All updates have been installed and I even reinstalled the siunitx package.

Here is a minimal working example that leads to the error:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please edit-in your `.log` file: you almost certainly have mismatched `siunitx` and `l3kernel` versions. Are you using MiKTeX by any chance?

Comment: looking at the whole `.log` file was the key. An old version of siunitx was loaded from a previous installation that I thought to be deleted entirely.
Deleting the rest of the old installation solved the problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because an old version of a file was found by LaTeX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An old version of `siunitx` from a different installation was loaded and caused the error.

Anybody who runs into this: Check your .log file